# In android show text of latin1_swidish_ci field in original decoded form

Tags: android, mysql, character-encoding, decode, iso-8859-1

I am reading text from DB and its collation type for text is latin1_swidish_ci and it is having some characters like this **streets â€” the new normal?** and its actual form is "**streets - the new normal?**" . How can is i decode this text to show the actual text?

Answer (score 0):

`â€”` is hex `E2 80 94` in latin1
`—` (em dash) is hex `E28094` in utf8

You have "Mojibake".  See [*this*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored) for discussion of what causes it and how to deal with it.